# Family Tree in java

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

I need to create a java program that can create a family tree in java. The program reads an input file in below format:

```
A is father of B
B is father of C
A is father of D
:
:
```

What I need to do is to create a family tree or whatever that seems logical. Then JUnit tests will run on my program, asking to return true or false like:
B is child of A, A is an ancestor of E......

Plus, I need to traverse the tree from left to right, and show hierarchy like:
A B C.....

I have thought of some logic, though I am new to Java. I have created a Person class, this has elements: Name, Left of Person type and Right of person type:

```
class Person {

    String name;
    Person left;
    Person right;
}
```

Plus I have added getters, setters and a constructor.

Then I read the file and create one person as:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));
String names[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
Person p = new Person(names[0]);
p.setLeft(new Person(names[4]));
```

I am totally confused at this stage and would benefit some guidance.
Thanks in advace

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.  StackOverflow is not a tutorial site. We cannot start from a few lines of code and explain how to accomplish what is a fairly involved task.  There is no short cut, this will be a significant amount of work and nobody here is going to write it for you.  Issues you will need to address include data input, building a model to represent the structure, storing the model in persistent storage (a db), displaying the data (graphics) and a lot more.

Comment: If you're trying to build something similar to one of the genealogy software packages currently available you'll have several person-years of work ahead of you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of left and right, better use 
`List< Person > children`, 
there's no point in using a binary tree for this problem.